# Display Rectangular Data Grid

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, visualisation

I'd like a *Linux* program which displays ASCII ArcGrid files (NxM rectangular ASCII data grids which may have either integer or floating point values). There is no practical upper or lower limit to these values.

I would like suggestions of a program which could read in this rectangular grid and display it in colour. The program must also have the capability to rescale the data so that I can isolate ranges of interest, it would be best if the rescaling could be nonlinear. (A nice, intuitive interface for this would be bestest.)

This is somewhat of a GIS application, so answers dependent upon conversion to the GeoTIFF format are acceptable.

Gimp did not work for me, so if you suggest it, you should be very specific about how to get it to display the GeoTIFF format (or a rectangular grid)

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with displaying it in QGIS?

Comment: You're certainly welcome to suggest this, @MerseyViking, if it has the ability to isolate/rescale data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following MerseyViking's comment, I used QGIS to open the files. Mike Toews' suggestion to use OpenEV was much appreciated, but the program did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

A simple program to view an manipulate rasters is [OpenEV](http://openev.sourceforge.net) (here is the [manual](http://openev.sourceforge.net/app/openevmain.html)). The software hasn't been updated in several years (2005?), which tells me it is not actively developed anymore. Frank Warmerdam is one of the lead developers of OpenEV, whom is also a lead developer of GDAL, GeoTIFF, etc.

Despite the old look and lack of recent development, I still find the program handy to use with rasters, since you can open a variety of formats, and have controls over scaling of each band.

[image: mainwindow]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://openev.sourceforge.net/app/mainwindow.gif))</sub>

Comment: It looks beautiful, Mike! But it segfaults when I try to load files.

Comment: How did you install? Source, binary? Try something like this: http://old.nabble.com/OpenEV2-on-Ubuntu-9.10-td26273054.html